# Python/Machine Learning: Can I combine several prediction models into one

Tags: python, model, machine-learning, classification

I am working on a prediction model and was initially using the random forest algorithm. I would like to combine different predicting algorithms into one to improve my accuracy.

I tried this, but I get an error:

```
models = [RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200), GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100)]
%time cross_val_score(models, X2, Y_target).mean()
```

Error:

```
estimator should a be an estimator implementing 'fit' method
```

Is there a way to do this? (Is there an easier way than bagging?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [VotingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html).

> The idea behind the voting classifier implementation is to combine
>   conceptually different machine learning classifiers and use a majority
>   vote or the average predicted probabilities (soft vote) to predict the
>   class labels.